# Why react router use browser history instead of hash history

Tags: react-router

The react-router document ([history](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory)) said:

> You might wonder why we don't fall back to hash history; the problem is that URLs become non-deterministic. If a visitor on hash history shares a URL with a visitor on browser history, and then they share that back, we end up with a terrible cartesian product of infinite potential URLs.

I got a little confused. An app only got one way to implement its history mechanism. A visitor shares a URL to another, they would both use browser history, or hash history. It is always the same.

Am I misunderstood something ? If not, why react router use browser history instead of hash history ? The hash history used to be the default history mechanism. Why change it ?

Answer (score 1):

> You might wonder why we don't fall back to hash history

In general it might be a good idea to fall back so old browsers don't make full reloads when not supporting browserHistory.

However, this would cause the trouble which is described in the quotation you gave, thus they decided to not fall back to hashHistory if the browser doesn't support browserHistory.

if they would fall back, an user with an old browser would have different urls than an user with a modern browser.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still dont get it. I think an app only got one way to implement its history mechanism. So if they fall back,  an user with an old browser and the user with modern browser would both have hash history. The urls in an app would be always the same.

Comment: @Bryce, the fall back would (and should) happen on runtime. so the app sees that the browser doesn't support browserHistory, it falls back to hashHistory for this specific user. other users might get other results depending on their browsers. that is what they wanted to avoid

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot.